# String passing between panels in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I'm using a VB.NET form that contains two panels; I want the user to be able to enter a string value in a `textbox` on panel 1, and have it appear in a `label` in panel 2.

Comment: The `Panels` are irrelevant. The form has access to all controls added to it. The code is in the form. The form gets data from one control and pushes it into another.

Comment: See the `TextChanged` event of your TextBox. You can set the same Text to another Control when this event is raised. So, even if a User pastes text in that TextBox, the other Control will receive it. If the Text entered is subject to validation, use the `Validate` / `Validated` events. Remember that you have an event-driven interface there. -- DataBindings is also an option. You should investigate this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Basic Example:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyUp

        Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text

End Sub
```

Don't worry about whether or not they're in different panels.

Comment: Many thanks, I was clearly overthinking the problem.

Comment: @Tallman82 Happens to us all. I think it happens more often the more you know, too, lol. Don't forget to mark as best answer if it did the trick!